# What is the need to set the environmental variable HUSKY_GAZEBO_DESCRIPTION?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was going through the husky_gazebo [wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/husky_gazebo/Tutorials/Simulating%20Husky) page.

The second step is this -

```
$ export HUSKY_GAZEBO_DESCRIPTION=$(rospack find husky_gazebo)/urdf/description.gazebo.xacro
```

Simply, launching the husky_gazebo simulation using roslaunch works fine -

```
$ roslaunch husky_gazebo husky_empty_world.launch
```

Why do we need the second step? Also, do we need to run that step every time before launching the husky_gazebo using roslaunch (third step)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/363921/what-is-the-need-to-set-the-environmental-variable-husky_gazebo_description?/) by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on ROS Answers with karma: 310 on 2020-10-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @skpro19,

The `HUSKY_GAZEBO_DESCRIPTION` as I see was an old variable to store the location of the Huyky description in old ROS versions of the package. Since the package is now fully integrated with `catkin` there is no need to set/use that environmental variable since the launch file is already calling the `find` directive. Maybe the tutorial is a bit obsolete and does not align with the new changes performed in new ROS distributions. But when I checked the package I was unable to find any chunk of code in which that particular environmental variable is used. So I would say that it has any usage now.

Regards.

---

Originally posted by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) with karma: 1695 on 2020-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2021-02-03**:
Makes sense. Thanks!